# Не работает Open Server — «Не удалось запустить MariaDB-10.3-x64»?

Tags: openserver

Вчера все нормально работало, сейчас нажимаю "Запустить", флаг становится желтым и через время обратно оранжевым. Зеленый цвет только при запуске системы, и то на самом деле не работает. Поискал в интернете, но решения для себя не нашел. Антивирус отключал, систему перезагружал. В чем проблема? 
Логи:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Долго мучился с ним, потом перешел на Denwer ) Не полный ответ, но может вы тоже передумаете.

Comment: А что, неплохо сидеть на денвере с mysql 5.5 и php 5.3 в то время как во всем мире уже php7.3 (скоро 7.4) и mysql 8

Comment: Надо конфиг-файлы смотреть, скорее всего ошибка там.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В моём случае случилось тоже самое, когда я чистил список баз данных и удалил "**mysql**" и "**information_schema**". После этого перестал запускаться сервер. Потом я скопировал из другой папки модуля OpenServer эти папки и сервер запустился.

Answer (score 1):

Тебе, наверное, уже не нужно, но может будет искать кто. Заходите в настройки Windows, затем в "Время и язык", "Регион", далее в "Дополнительные параметры даты и времени", потом в "Региональные стандарты", нажимаете вкладку "Дополнительно" (она сверху), далее клацаете "Изменить язык системы" и убираете галочку с "Бета-версия: использовать ...". Перезагружаете комп. Должно помочь.

Answer (score 1):

Столкнулся с похожей проблемой. Из дня в день все запускалось, а однажды сломалось.
Помогло удаление файлов(попробуйте повытаскивать по очереди или вместе):

```
ib_buffer_pool
aria_log (2).00000001
aria_log_control
```

После того как их убрал, сервер запустился без ошибок.

Answer (score 0):

А на каком порту висит СУБД? У меня такое было, только с PostreSQL. Оказалось, что порт был занят другим процессом и сервер с СУБД не мог нормально стартануть.

Comment: 27017, если я правильно посмотрел.

Comment: @Dvornik 27017 - это mongo. Mysql обычно на 3306.

Comment: А, ну да. Mysql На 3306. Другие процессы не занимают порт.

Comment: покажи настройки mongo

Comment: Я перепутал с mongo, у меня MariaDB не запускается.

Comment: посмотри порт MariaDB, занят ли он каким - нибудь другим процессом ( можно через netstat -ao в командной строке это сделать. Там узнаешь PID процесса, а в диспетчере задач по PID узнаешь , что за процесс висит на этом порту). Если не занят, что скинь настройки СУБД, будем смотреть.

Comment: Кажется я понял, я в БД удалил таблицу mysql, как-то так называлась. В других каталогах версий mariadb есть такая папка, а в используемой - нет. // Да, именно так, скопировал папку и все заработало. А столько времени потерял...