# Не удалось запустить MariaDB-10.3

Tags: база-данных, windows, веб-сервер, openserver, mariadb

Не запускается Openserver. Посмотрел лог запуска OpenServer-а и увидел следующее

```
2023-05-13 09:12:44  --------------------------------------------
2023-05-13 09:12:44  Начало процедуры запуска сервера
2023-05-13 09:12:44  Обновление Hosts файла
2023-05-13 09:12:44  Обновление конфигурации MariaDB-10.3
2023-05-13 09:12:44  Обновление конфигурации Sendmail
2023-05-13 09:12:44  Обновление конфигурации PHP_7.4
2023-05-13 09:12:44  Обновление конфигурации Redis-4.0
2023-05-13 09:12:44  Обновление конфигурации PHPRedisAdmin
2023-05-13 09:12:44  Обновление конфигурации PHPMyAdmin
2023-05-13 09:12:44  Обновление конфигурации Apache_2.4-PHP_7.0-7.1
2023-05-13 09:12:44  Запуск MariaDB-10.3
2023-05-13 09:12:44  Запуск Redis-4.0
2023-05-13 09:12:44  Запуск Apache_2.4-PHP_7.0-7.1
2023-05-13 09:12:44  Проверка состояния сервера
2023-05-13 09:13:14  Не удалось запустить MariaDB-10.3
2023-05-13 09:13:14  Сбой запуска!
2023-05-13 09:13:14  --------------------------------------------
2023-05-13 09:13:14  Начало процедуры остановки сервера
2023-05-13 09:13:14  Остановка системных модулей
2023-05-13 09:13:44  Отключение виртуального диска
2023-05-13 09:13:44  Сервер успешно остановлен за 29,953 секунд!
```

Как можно устранить ошибку

```
2023-05-13 09:13:14  Не удалось запустить MariaDB-10.3
```

так чтобы не потерять поддержку проектов, созданных на основе базы MariaDB-10.3?

P.S. В настройках Openserver-а менял тип базы данных

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в результате выдало ошибку

```
[Bitrix\Main\DB\ConnectionException] 
Mysql connect error [localhost]: (1045) Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (400)
C:\OpenServer\domains\mylasttechnoshop.ru\bitrix\modules\main\lib\db\mysqliconnection.php:82
#0: Bitrix\Main\DB\MysqliConnection->connectInternal
    C:\OpenServer\domains\mylasttechnoshop.ru\bitrix\modules\main\lib\data\connection.php:53
#1: Bitrix\Main\Data\Connection->getResource
    C:\OpenServer\domains\mylasttechnoshop.ru\bitrix\modules\main\lib\db\mysqlisqlhelper.php:21
#2: Bitrix\Main\DB\MysqliSqlHelper->forSql
    C:\OpenServer\domains\mylasttechnoshop.ru\bitrix\modules\main\lib\config\option.php:206
#3: Bitrix\Main\Config\Option::load
    C:\OpenServer\domains\mylasttechnoshop.ru\bitrix\modules\main\lib\config\option.php:83
#4: Bitrix\Main\Config\Option::getRealValue
    C:\OpenServer\domains\mylasttechnoshop.ru\bitrix\modules\main\lib\config\option.php:32
#5: Bitrix\Main\Config\Option::get
    C:\OpenServer\domains\mylasttechnoshop.ru\bitrix\modules\main\lib\httprequest.php:394
#6: Bitrix\Main\HttpRequest->prepareCookie
    C:\OpenServer\domains\mylasttechnoshop.ru\bitrix\modules\main\lib\httprequest.php:71
#7: Bitrix\Main\HttpRequest->__construct
    C:\OpenServer\domains\mylasttechnoshop.ru\bitrix\modules\main\lib\httpapplication.php:49
#8: Bitrix\Main\HttpApplication->initializeContext
    C:\OpenServer\domains\mylasttechnoshop.ru\bitrix\modules\main\lib\application.php:133
#9: Bitrix\Main\Application->initializeExtendedKernel
    C:\OpenServer\domains\mylasttechnoshop.ru\bitrix\modules\main\include.php:1
#10: require_once(string)
    C:\OpenServer\domains\mylasttechnoshop.ru\bitrix\modules\main\include\prolog_before.php:14
#11: require_once(string)
    C:\OpenServer\domains\mylasttechnoshop.ru\bitrix\modules\main\include\prolog.php:10
#12: require_once(string)
    C:\OpenServer\domains\mylasttechnoshop.ru\bitrix\header.php:1
#13: require(string)
    C:\OpenServer\domains\mylasttechnoshop.ru\index.php:2
----------
```

Добавляю еще логи

`MariaDB-10.3_error.log`

```
2023-05-13 14:39:29 0 [Note] c:\openserver\modules\database\MariaDB-10.3\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 10.3.22-MariaDB-log) starting as process 6940 ...
2023-05-13 14:39:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2023-05-13 14:39:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2023-05-13 14:39:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2023-05-13 14:39:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2023-05-13 14:39:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2023-05-13 14:39:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2023-05-13 14:39:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2023-05-13 14:39:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=913341107
2023-05-13 14:40:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2023-05-13 14:40:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2023-05-13 14:40:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2023-05-13 14:40:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'c:\openserver\userdata\MariaDB-10.3\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2023-05-13 14:40:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'c:\openserver\userdata\MariaDB-10.3\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2023-05-13 14:40:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.22 started; log sequence number 913341116; transaction id 1656039
2023-05-13 14:40:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from c:\openserver\userdata\MariaDB-10.3\ib_buffer_pool
2023-05-13 14:40:02 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2023-05-13 14:40:02 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
2023-05-13 14:40:02 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
2023-05-13 14:40:02 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
2023-05-13 14:40:02 0 [Note] c:\openserver\modules\database\MariaDB-10.3\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '10.3.22-MariaDB-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
2023-05-13 14:40:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 230513 14:40:04
```

`MariaDB-10.3_queries.log`

```
c:\openserver\modules\database\MariaDB-10.3\bin\mysqld.exe, Version: 10.3.22-MariaDB-log (mariadb.org binary distribution). started with:
TCP Port: 3306, Named Pipe: (null)
Time            Id Command  Argument
```

`Apache_2.4-PHP_7.0-7.1_errora.log`

```
[Sat May 13 14:39:31.134144 2023] [ssl:warn] [pid 12452:tid 132] AH01909: mylasttechnoshop.ru:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat May 13 14:39:33.050254 2023] [ssl:warn] [pid 4600:tid 144] AH01909: bx24site1.ru:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat May 13 14:39:33.050254 2023] [ssl:warn] [pid 4600:tid 144] AH01909: bookstore:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat May 13 14:39:33.051254 2023] [ssl:warn] [pid 4600:tid 144] AH01909: bookscourse.ru:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat May 13 14:39:33.051254 2023] [ssl:warn] [pid 4600:tid 144] AH01909: angularcliproject:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat May 13 14:39:33.052254 2023] [ssl:warn] [pid 4600:tid 144] AH01909: alivio:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat May 13 14:39:33.053254 2023] [ssl:warn] [pid 4600:tid 144] AH01909: alcoholstore:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat May 13 14:39:33.053254 2023] [ssl:warn] [pid 4600:tid 144] AH01909: AdminLTE-3.2.0:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat May 13 14:39:33.054254 2023] [ssl:warn] [pid 4600:tid 144] AH01909: adaptive-burning-man.ru:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat May 13 14:39:33.055254 2023] [ssl:warn] [pid 4600:tid 144] AH01909: AdamariLopez:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat May 13 14:39:33.055254 2023] [ssl:warn] [pid 4600:tid 144] AH01909: A:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat May 13 14:39:33.056254 2023] [ssl:warn] [pid 4600:tid 144] AH01909: 2rism:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat May 13 14:39:33.056254 2023] [ssl:warn] [pid 4600:tid 144] AH01909: default:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat May 13 14:39:33.116258 2023] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4600:tid 144] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Смотрел [Не удалось запустить MariaDB-10.3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1018012/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-open-server-%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-mariadb-10-3-x64), но не помогло. Я не понял, что

**1.** на этой странице имел ввиду Yaroslav Kravchenko - я не нашел "Бета-версия: использовать ...",

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

эта настройка есть в windows 10 (см. https://ospanel.io/docs/), в windows 7 нет.

**2.** а файлы удалять, как советовал Lev Kirillov, не решился - потому что побоялся, что сайт (помещенный в папку C
:\OpenServer\domains) будет работать неверно.

Comment: логи апача, пхп и запросов тут не к месту. А вот логи марии у вас время не совпадает с тем, которое на первом скрине.  Посмотрите, мб там еще какие логи есть.