# Переустановка OpenServer-а

Tags: база-данных, windows, phpmyadmin, openserver, mariadb

В связи с [Не удалось запустить MariaDB-10.3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1519392/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-mariadb-10-3) я решил переустановить OpenServer. Я скопировал папку с сайтом `C:\OpenServer\domains\mylasttechnoshop.ru` (это сайт на битриксе) в `D:\`. Но также необходимо перетащить файлы базы данных. Я искал папки с базой данных для сайта `mylasttechnoshop.ru` и нашел только `C:\OpenServer\userdata\MariaDB-10.3\mylasttechnoshop` (создана в PhpMyAdmin). Вопрос в том, что всё ли я скопировал (всё ли по базе данных) для переноса проекта на новый OpenServer?

P. S. Для сайта mylasttechnoshop.ru все ли данные располагаются в двух местах - `C:\OpenServer\domains\mylasttechnoshop.ru` и `C:\OpenServer\userdata\MariaDB-10.3\mylasttechnoshop`?

Comment: Дамп базы данных делали?

Comment: Нет. А как сделать?

Comment: я не дамп делаю, а копию. Просто когда я буду переносить сайт на новый OpenServer все ли данные я охватил?

Comment: Зайдите в phpMyAdmin и просто экспортируйте все БД которые Вам нужны. Потом сделаете импорт.