# Лучший сервер баз данных в OpenServer для создания сайтов на Битриксе

Tags: mysql, windows, битрикс, openserver, mariadb

Хочу создать сайт на Битриксе. В связи с [Не удалось запустить MariaDB-10.3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1519392/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-mariadb-10-3) возник вопрос: " Какой сервер баз данных выбрать в настройках OpenServer - MariaDB-10.1, MariaDB-10.2, MariaDB-10.3, MariaDB-10.4, MySQL - 5.1,..., MySQL-8.0, чтобы ошибки часто не возникали?"

Comment: Просто почитайте системные требования. 5.1 вроде вообще не поддерживается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исходя из [официальных требований к 1С-Битрикс: Управление сайтом](https://www.1c-bitrix.ru/products/cms/requirements.php) нужно использовать MySQL 5.6 и выше. Смело ставим 5.6 - 5.7.

Если нужно использовать MariaDB, то нужно выбрать 10.2 и выше. MariaDB 10.0 и MariaDB 10.1 функционируют как ограниченная замена MySQL 5.6 . Тем не менее, есть некоторые различия в реализации некоторых функций. Версия MariaDB 10.2 наиболее совместима с MySQL 5.7. Более подробно вопрос совместимости описан на [официальном ресурсе](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/).

Если отсутствуют ограничения, то ставим MySQL и не думаем о совместимости с MariaDB.

При создания сайта с нуля лучше использовать php 8.1, так как Битрикс [ограничил техническую поддержку](https://helpdesk.bitrix24.ru/open/17332020/) на версии 7.4 и ниже. Также php 8.1 более современен.